# How to emit string into user control from code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have a main aspx page in which there is a list of items. Each item is shown using the user control.
Now i am trying to emit string in user control is page receives specific parameter through user control as below.

```
//ASCX code
..
<span><%=custString %></span>
..
// .CS code
protected string custString = string.Empty;
..
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if(Request.params["chages_done"]){
custString = "Values updated ";
}
}
```

So while debugging i can see the value of the string getting updated but its not getting reflected on the ascx control when its added to page. Any idea how it can be achived ? or what can be wrong ?
I have also  tried to create the server side control in user control and setting its value from code behind but it too was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a public string property to your control, and a Literal control to the .ascx markup. When the property is set, set the value of the Literal control as well. Should do the trick.

Comment: Can you show your new code? With the public property, you can set the value from the containing .aspx page, you don't have to do the check inside the web user control.

Comment: Yes it worked ... the page was getting reloaded twice took some time to figure it out ... thanks ... :)